# images appear to 'shear' when swiping past them

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm getting some odd behavior when viewing one of my sites on an ipad 2 (and ipad 3 for that matter).

The site is a very tall infographic that requires the user to scroll/swipe their way through. All of the images are either `img` tags or backgrounds on divs/spans/paragraphs and are absolutely positioned. Some of my images appear to shear when I swipe past them.

Here is an [animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pufjq.gif) that shows what I am seeing (don't stare at it for too long, it might be hypnotic):

[image: scroll shear]

The image should actually look like:

[image: original image]

The image in my example isn't particularly big. It's only a 110kb 24bit png.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: That animated gif is awesome O.O

Comment: @RocketHazmat - it's a thing of beauty. I'm hoping it will lead to a solution!

Comment: If you want a solution, then you will need to provide your code. Also if possible a link to the site or a http://jsfiddle.net with the issue replicated.

Comment: It's an internal project so unfortunately I can't provide the code. The issue comes up from time to time so it isn't something I can replicate all the time. I'm thinking it could be something to do with memory management on the ipad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but you can try to f[orce Safari to use hardware acceleration](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d) by applying the following style to the element containing the image:

```
.forceAccel > * { -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); }
```

It does usually fix the flickering issues, as long as I have tested.

Comment: Interesting theory - I'm going to give this a go.